# Twitter Bootstrap Template with Spring MVC

Tags: web-applications, spring-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, jspx, apache-tiles

I'm trying to setup twitter bootstrap with spring mvc.  I moved all the bootstrap (bootstrap.css and bootstrap-responsive.css) into the resource folder and linked it to the jspx page.  I copied/pasted the Starter Template (http://tinyurl.com/ojnjovk) into the view.jpsx.

The page loads fine on start e.g. the black bar is where is supposed to be (at top).  Problem is when I resize the window, bar just drops down the page and the height of the responsive button is smaller than usual.

I have no idea what could be causing this.  Any suggestions?

To simulate the setup create a mvc project, setup apache tiles, copy the above template into .jspx page and run it.

All .css files are loaded correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Open up your Chrome developer tools or Firebug and make sure that your  CSS and JS resources are getting loaded correctly.  I.e. if your view.jspx loads your bootstrap css with a link element like so: `<link href="../assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">` then you need to make sure your bootstrap.css file is located in the `assets/css/` directory.  Same for JavaScript.  If your browser is unable to load these, you should see console errors or 404 responses in the Network tab.

Comment: Aready checked - bootstrap.css files are correctly loaded. Plus top bar would not be visible on start if files were not.

Comment: turns out there was a css problem I had to add !important to get to work:  @media (max-width: 979px) {
  body {
    padding-top: 0 !important;
  }...